# Will JS object literals defined in a function be optimized?

Tags: javascript, function, object, optimization, literals

Will JavaScript optimize an object literal defined in a method?  Suppose I have a simple lookup function that gets used extensively:

```
function lookup(value) {
    return {
        "A": "a",
        "B": "b",
        "C": "c"
    }[value];
}
```

Is there any benefit to defining the object outside of the function for reuse, or will the engine optimize that away for me?

Comment: The first question that comes to mind is: Which engine? V8? SpiderMonkey? JScript? Which *version* of those engines?

Comment: If the function was only called once any kind of internal memoization would be the opposite of an optimisation.  Combine both approaches by encapsulating the table in a LookupHelper object that constructs the object only once.

Comment: No specific engine, just in general.

Comment: @MichaelPayne: Well, that's the problem. Different engines do different things. Frankly, I wouldn't rely on it. If the function is used extensively, I'd just do `var lookup = (function() { var index = {...}; return function lookup(value) { return index[value]; })();` But "I wouldn't rely on it" isn't an answer to your question. :-)

Comment: Wouldn't it be a good idea to at least declare your object literal as a `const`?

Comment: I would *love* to roll up my sleeves and see what V8, SpiderMonkey, and (say) Edge's version of JScript do with this. But I just can't invest that time. I hope someone does.

Comment: I have no idea, but I would think that most engines are smart enough to garbage collect that object every time as it's not really used for anything other than returning a primitive value from the function. Then again, who knows, might be easier to just define the object outside the function, that way you're sure you don't have a lot of rogue objects in memory.

Comment: You can safely assume that the engine will make any and all appropriate optimizations and you don't have to worry about it. Even if the engine did NOT make any optimizations, the difference would likely be measured in microseconds.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Is JScript still in existence? Shouldn't this properly be called Chakra?

Comment: @torazaburo: Good point, that's what they called the fork for Edge.

Comment: @adeneo: Yeah. Barring some *further* optimization, V8 at least will allocate that object on the stack and pop the stack on exit, never touching the heap.

Comment: At the end of the day, unless you've noticed a problem with `lookup`, this is premature optimization. As torazaburo mentions, the difference between an unoptimized version of that and an optimized version will be effectively nothing. Even if the unoptimized version took 2-3 times as long to run, in real terms, it would be a difference not worth worrying about.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
var object = {
 "A": "a",
 "B": "b",
 "C": "c"
};

function lookup1(value) {
    return object[value];
}

function lookup2(value) {
    return {
  "A": "a",
  "B": "b",
  "C": "c"
 }[value];
}

var dateBefore = new Date().getTime();
for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
 var a = lookup2('A');
}
var dateAfter = new Date().getTime();

console.log(dateAfter - dateBefore);

var dateBefore = new Date().getTime();
for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
 var a = lookup1('A');
}
var dateAfter = new Date().getTime();

console.log(dateAfter - dateBefore);
```

Comment: "Is there any benefit to defining the object outside of the function for reuse, or will the engine optimize that away for me?"
The first answer. And I demonstrated you.

Comment: Thank you for that.  Not a lot of difference but it answers my question that there IS a difference and at least the engine this test is using does not optimize for me.

Comment: @MichaelPayne, maybe you have a look to the direct call, at my post.

Comment: "Direct call" and calling through a function have same time.

Comment: @Laurianti, not with my browser. 1944 - 1422 - 206. (edge)

Comment: Really? In chrome are same. In Firefox similar.

Comment: in chrome it's 504 - 151 - 151.

Comment: I think this is what `console.time` is for.